# MongoDB - locahost Not authorized on admin to execute command

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to initialize a config replica set on a single member. If I run,

```
mongo --host localhost:27017
```

It works but as soon as I run the command to initialize the replica set.

```
rs.initiate({_id : "c_rs1", configsvr: true, members: [{ _id: 1, host : "10.0.0.2:2701"}]})
```

I get this error

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetInitiate: { _id: \"c_rs1\", configsvr: true, members: [ { _id: 1.0, host: \"10.0.0.2:27017\" } ] } }",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
}
```

However, if I run this instead

```
mongo --port 27017
```

We get this when we run the exact same command.

```
{ ok : 1 }
```

This is a problem when I have to run the script to initialize a replica set on a different server because I cannot simply define the host and assume there's a config mongod instance running on the right port on the same server. Any ideas on why the `--host` option isn't working at the moment?

FYI: security.authentication = disabled in the config file for the mongod

Comment: what is this ip `10.0.0.2`? is the `hosts` file changed?

Comment: it's the IP address of the localhost. I just copy pasted directly from the file I didn't bother changing it.